# 14.04 - cannot click inside windows

Tags: 14.04, click-policy

I have Asus k53sv, Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 were working without problems.
Now I upgraded to 14.04.

Upper panel works, so I can connect into WiFi or shutdown machine. I can also launch application from left launch bar.
But most applications are not responding to mouse clicks:

- Folders: I can not open any folder. I see my home folder, but application is not responding to clicking.
- system preferences: the same as above, not responding to clicking.
- terminal: can type, but no response to clicking.
- In any application 'red x' is not closing application, to shut it down I have to right-click on launch bar and select 'Quit' option.

For a while of using system (Chrome is working normally, so it is not mouse problem) I cannot even launch application from launch bar.
I tried to boot with older kernel (from grub options) but result is the same.

Any ideas how to fix it? I can do some debug work if you tell me what to do.
I would like to do not re-install whole system from scratch, I have installed and configured some applications (Eclipse, Kile) I and do not want to configure them again.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved, my Madcatz RAT 3 mouse was causing this strange behaviour, solved as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ScDa8Qqqgc)

First, identify the device by running

```
xinput -list
```

In the section `Virtual Core Pointer` identify the exact name of the mouse. In my case, it's

```
Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3
```

copy that name, and then make an in entry in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`...

```
sudo -i
gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Now enter this, using the device name from `xinput -list` in the `MatchProduct` line

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifiers "Mouse Remap"
MatchProduct "Madcats Mad Catz R.A.T.3"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Save the file, close it and enter `exit` in the terminal to drop privileges. After reboot, the mouse works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try switching off the your computer and switching it on. It worked for me.

Comment: but will that have a lasting effect?